# How to add new admin user without using of devise in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am new in Ruby on Rails and I am using Ruby 1.9.3 andRails 4.0.2.

How can I add a new admin user without using of devise?

I am using below code and submit add new user form with data `admin_user_params` returns a  blank and a blank record is inserted in database.

**This my user db table**

```
create_table :users do |t|
  t.integer :role_id
  t.string :name
  t.string :email
  t.string :username
  t.string :encrypted_password
  t.string :reset_password_token
  t.string :is_status
  t.string :is_active
  t.integer :sign_in_count
  t.string :current_sign_in_ip
  t.string :last_sign_in_ip
  t.string :authentication_token
  t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at
  t.datetime :remember_created_at
  t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
  t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
```

**this is my controller**

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_admin_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @admin_user = User.new
  end



 def create
    #@admin_user = Admin::User.new(admin_user_params)
    @admin_user = User.new(admin_user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @admin_user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @admin_user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @admin_user }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @admin_user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**This is my User Model **

**Note:**

I don't want to create admin_user model. I want to using only User model for admin area and fronted area.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  #Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :name, :username, :role_id, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :id, :admin_permission
  attr_accessor :password, :new_password, :previous_email, :previous_username, :remember_me

  belongs_to :role

  def super_admin?
   self.role.name == "Super Admin"
  end
end
```

**This is my View**

```
<%= form_for [:admin,@admin_user]  do |f| %>
  <% if @admin_user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@admin_user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this admin_user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @admin_user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Username %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Password %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :encrypted_password %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <p><%= f.submit 'Sign up'  %></p>
  </div>
 <% end %>
```

Please Help.

Comment: remove attr_accessor from your user model and write attributes in attr_accessible.

Comment: You have `:admin_permission` as an `attribute_acessible` but I don't see this in your table design? `admin_user_params` is not assigned to anything you would use the `params` hash. This might become clearer if you validated the records in your model. Also having :id as an accessible attribute creates some concern as it could allow a falsified update request to set a new id.

Comment: Sorry just wanted to point out the same concern for `:role_id`. Say `role_id 1` = `Admin Role`. Assuming you have a form that lets me change my email address and use the standard `update_attributes` method. This would allow me to intercept the request and add a parameter to the params hash that says `role_id =1` and when that request is processed through the update method I am now assigned an `Admin Role`. If you removed the `attribute_accessible` then it would become a `MassAssignment Error`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to add admin user functionality is to add a boolean `admin` row to your `users` table.

Then, in your controllers, you can control access to specific actions with a `before_action` that ensures the user is an admin, or else redirects to `root_url` (or wherever).

You can also selectively view elements in your views by calling `User#admin?` in a conditional.

Not sure if that meets your needs, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

A nice flexible way to do this would be to use [Rolify](https://github.com/EppO/rolify) + [Authority](https://github.com/nathanl/authority). This will allow you to assign admin roles to users in addition to other roles. From there you can control access to specific methods based on those roles.

The roles are applied to the users by associations, so you can ask questions like

```
@user.has_role? :admin
```

This can be scoped globally, to models or to instances of models. Fine grain control while being easy to use.